# What does Perl's -p command-line switch do?

Tags: perl

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/search_str/replace_str/g' filename
```

What do `-p`, `-i.bak` `s/` and `/g` mean?

Answer (score 13):

- `-p`: assume '`while (<>) { ... }`'
  loop around program and print each
  processed line too.
- `-i.bak`: change the input file
  (`filename`) inplace and create the
  file `filename.bak` as backup.
- `s in s/`: to mark substitution
- `g` - make the substitution
  globally..that is don't stop after
  first replacement.

Comment: Your definition of `-p` is missing the `print` statement. Are you confusing it with `-n`?

Comment: Aha, it's wrong for a different reason then: it doesn't print the input line, it prints the processed line. :P

Answer (score 8):

From [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2A-p%2A):

> #### `-p`
>
> causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed:
>
> ```
>   LINE:
>     while (<>) {
>         ...             # your program goes here
>     } continue {
>         print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This piece of code:

`perl
-p
-i.bak
-e
's/search_str/replace_str/g'
filename`

Is essentially the same as:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
$extension = '.orig';
LINE:
  while (<>) {
    # -i.bak
    if ($ARGV ne $oldargv) {
      if ($extension !~ /\*/) {
        $backup = $ARGV . $extension;
      } else {
        ($backup = $extension) =~ s/\*/$ARGV/g;
      }
      rename($ARGV, $backup);
      open(ARGVOUT, ">$ARGV");
      select(ARGVOUT);
      $oldargv = $ARGV;
    }

    s/search_str/replace_str/g;

  } continue {
    print;  # this prints to original filename
  }

select(STDOUT);
```

Answer (score 2):

See [perldoc perlrun.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

This one-liner changes every occurrence of  `search_str` to `replace_str` in every line of the file, automatically printing the resulting line.

The `-i.bak` switch causes it to change the file in-place and store a backup to another file with the `.bak` extension.

Answer (score 2):

It will automatically read a line from the diamond operator, execute the script, and then print $_.

For more details visit the following link.

[Perl -p](http://affy.blogspot.com/p5be/ch17.htm)

Answer (score 1):

1.causes perl to assume the following loop around your script, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed:

2. Note that the lines are printed automatically. To suppress printing use the -n switch. A -p overrides a -n switch.

[link text](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/rgs/mosaic/pl-opt.html)