# Using tee and process subsitution together yields a strange result

Tags: bash, unix

Please take a lookt at the following command:

```
   ===> echo "hi" | tee >(sed -e 's/hi/wow/') | tail | perl -pe 's/hi/janet/;print "holy\n"'
holy
janet
holy
wow
```

How come `holy` is printed twice here?

I was expecting the outcome to be

```
holy
janet
wow
```

Answer (score 1):

We can distill your code to a simpler form:

```
(echo hi; echo wow) | perl -pe 'print "holy\n"'
```

Now, this feeds two lines to `perl`, whose `-p` option means "[Read lines from stdin and print them also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476919/what-does-perls-p-command-line-switch-do)."  And we tell Perl to print "holy" as well.  So for each input line, we print "holy" then the input line, so it's no surprise that two lines become four.  Probably your surprise stems from not realizing the mechanics of `-p`--it behaves as if your entire script is put into a loop over all input lines.